# k-nearest neighbour script for each data point

Tags: python, knn

I have a large set of features which looks like this:

```
x1 28273 20866 29961 27190 31790 19714 8643 14482 5384 ....  upto 1000  
x2 12343 45634 29961 27130 33790 14714 7633 15483 4484 ....  
x3 ..... ..... ..... ..... ..... ..... .... ..... .... ....
.  
.  
.  
.  
x1000 .... .... ... ..  .  .  .  .
```

I am trying to calculate the k-nearest neighbor for each feature, for `k=5`. I am using numpy and scipy package, however, it seems to be computationally complex because of large (1000 x 1000) dataset. Is there a simpler way to compute kNN using python?

Answer (score 1):

[You should use scikits.learn](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/neighbors.html).